# How to put the "login" button aligned at right?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am a `CSS` beginner, I want to achieve a layout for a header where there is  the logo at left and a login button at right but the header and login button should be both aligned. And below this buttons there is the menu.

It's  working fine, but I am not understanding how to put the login button "login" at the right using `flexbox` and not with float right.

Do you know how to achieve that?

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/gyw381L5/

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.header {
  background-color: orange;
}

.container {
  max-width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

header {
  background-color: orange;
}

.nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.nav a {
  padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="main">
      <h1>Logo</h1>
      <a>Login</a>
    </div>
    <div class="nav">
      <a href="">Link 1</a>
      <a href="">Link 2</a>
      <a href="">Link 3</a>
      <a href="">Link 4</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just need to add this to your CSS

```
.main {
  display: flex;
}

.main > h1 {
  flex: 1;
}
```

You could simplify your markup. See below: (just an option)

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0; 
}

header{
  background-color: orange;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 800px;
}

nav {
  flex: 1;
  text-align: center;
}

nav > a {
  padding: 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Logo</h1>
    <nav>
      <a href="">Link 1</a>
      <a href="">Link 2</a>
      <a href="">Link 3</a>
      <a href="">Link 4</a>
    </nav>
    <div>Login</div>
  </div>
</header>
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/szb5u6e1/10/)

Answer (score 1):

just give class main this css: 
`.main {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between
}`

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.header {
  background-color: orange;
}

.container {
  max-width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

header {
  background-color: orange;
}

.nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.nav a {
  padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px;
}

.main {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between
}
```

```html
<header>

  <div class="container">

    <div class="main">
      <h1>Logo</h1>
      <a>Login</a>
    </div>
    <div class="nav">
      <a href="">Link 1</a>
      <a href="">Link 2</a>
      <a href="">Link 3</a>
      <a href="">Link 4</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: ignore my revision - sorry. i thought i was changing mine

Comment: no, no. I accidentally hit edit on your response when I went to make changes to my own answer. I was apologizing :)

Comment: sorry! its okay :)

Answer (score 0):

I have given code here

```
<header>
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Logo</h1>
    <nav>
      <a href="">Link 1</a>
      <a href="">Link 2</a>
      <a href="">Link 3</a>
      <a href="">Link 4</a>
    </nav>
    <div>Login</div>
  </div>
</header>
```

and CSS here

```
.main {
  display: flex;
}

.main > h1 {
  flex: 1;
}
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0; 
}

header{
  background-color: orange;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 800px;
}

nav {
  flex: 1;
  text-align: center;
}

nav > a {
  padding: 0 10px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gyw381L5/7/

thanks